# Default selection on select control

Tags: angular

How can I make a default selection on a select control with an array of strings.

This works:

```html
            <select class="form-control"
                    [ngModel]="defaultSubscription"
                    name="subscription">                
                <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
                <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
                <option value="Pro">Pro</option>
            </select>
```

But this one does NOT:

```html
            <select class="form-control"
                    [ngModel]="defaultSubscription"
                    name="subscription">
                <option *ngFor="let subsciption of subscriptions"
                        value="{{subscription}}">
                    {{subsciption}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets

```
let subscriptions = ['subscription1', 'subscription2'];

<select class="form-control"
                [ngModel]="defaultSubscription"
                name="subscription">
            <option *ngFor="let subsciption of subscriptions"
                    [value]="subscription">
                {{subsciption}}
            </option>
</select>
```

Comment: used your code, default selection still does not work, did you verify your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `value` and it should work as you want, it's not needed here:

```
<select class="form-control"
    [ngModel]="defaultSubscription"
    name="subscription">
  <option *ngFor="let subsciption of subscriptions">{{subsciption}}</option>
</select>
```

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YmctqaWQQUxbonNwcIl5?p=preview)

Comment: No problem! :) Good that you got many working solutions, you can pick and choose depending on the mood :P